# Google Apps Scripting Issue

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, freshdesk

1) I am trying to create a complete script that will take input data from a google form/google sheet and use the top row as as field names for a Freshdesk ticket while taking the last row (most current) as the data to input as the ticket data ..

2) I have coded onFormSubmit portion so it creates the general ticket however i would the data from the backend to be used as the certain field data

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
    if ((typeof GasFreshdesk)==='undefined') {
        eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zixia/gas-freshdesk/master/src/gas-freshdesk-lib.js').getContentText())
    }
    var MyFreshdesk = new GasFreshdesk('https://***.freshdesk.com', 'API KEY'); // REPLACE redacted with real key

    // Custom fields passed in. Use this for now - to test (then replace later with other valid values).
   var customFields = {"email": "firstnamelastname@org.org",
                        "room": "IT",
                        "building": "**",
                        "devicesystem": "Device",
                        "problem": "problem"

    };

    var ticket = new MyFreshdesk.Ticket({description: "We have provided you with a loaner",
                                                       subject: "** - Device - Problem- " + "FullName", email: "firstnamelastname@org.org",
                                                               type: "Support Request", custom_fields: customFields});
                                                             }
```

What i'm looking for is a way to grab the values in the last row of data since that data is what will need to be inputted into the ticket.

```
  function LastRow() {
   var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  var lr = getLastRow();


  Logger.log(lr);
}
```

Comment: That data should be found in the onFormSubmit event object as either `namedValues` or `values`....read about the [event object here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)

Comment: namedValues would be great since it has the headers as key and the current data as values.

Comment: I believe you are missing the following for getting the last element of your sheet: ```lastElement = ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow(),ss.getLastColumn()).getValue();```. Let me know if that solved the issue :D